# What is wrong with this LaTeX equation?

Tags: math-mode, errors

In the math mode, I am typing an equation and I am constantly getting errors such as

Undefined Control Sequence etc.

I have tried all things to my knowledge, but I am missing something. Can someone help me?

```
\begin{equation}
    \large \alpha_b = \left\{
      {\text{1, I_{i,r}^b \geq I_{thr}} \atop
      \text{0, I_{i,r}^b < I_{thr}}
    \right}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `_` is a math mode command. It must only appear in math mode. You have it within `\text{ ... }` which puts you in text mode unsurprisingly. So `_` is undefined and fails

Comment: Also you seem to have `\right}` at the end, where I assume you want `\right\}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct way to type in the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\alpha_b =
\begin{cases}
1, & I_{i,r}^b \geq I_{thr} \\
0, & I_{i,r}^b < I_{thr}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on its meaning, “thr” could be better as

```
I_{\mathrm{thr}}
```

Use this if it's a textual abbreviation.

---

About your code, it's hard to find something right, I'm afraid.

The command `\large` is not allowed in math mode. Probably you wanted to use it for enlarging the result of `\atop`. But `\atop` is not to be used anywhere in LaTeX, if you load `amsmath` (and you do, because you have `\text`).

The command `\text` is used to insert textual parts in an equation, but you're using it for math parts; finally `\right}` is not allowed and it should be `\right.` for a null delimiter.

However, using a fraction for doing a `cases` environment is wrong to begin with. I'm quite surprised you know about `\atop` and not about `cases`. If `\atop` has been suggested to you by a friend, this could be a good occasion for breaking this friendship. `;-)`

Comment: takes his TeX seriously, you understand? You don't wanna know what happened to the guy who ended all his paragraphs with ``\\`` :P :)

Comment: @Au101 Students who do that don't get their degree!

Comment: Maybe it's better to load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. (I know it doesn't make a difference here.) Also, what's the difference between `\mathrm` and `\textup` in the subscript?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I think that `mathtools` should be rewritten from scratch, so I load it only when it's really necessary.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what you don't like about `mathtools`? So far I thought that it is very well recommended in the community. (it's an old comment of you - maybe it's outdated)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The code is an unreadable mix of classical and obsolete expl3-like style. Very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \alpha_b
  = \left\{\frac{1, I_{i,r}^b \geq I_{thr}}{0, I_{i,r}^b < I_{thr}}\right\}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
  \alpha_b
  = \left\{\frac{1, I_{i,r}^b \geq I_{\mathrm{thr}}}{0, I_{i,r}^b < I_{\mathrm{thr}}}\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The latter should be used if the subscripts to the right are text.